# registerhotkey doesnt triggers for shift or control keys, but works for letter keys

Tags: c#, registerhotkey

I have simple app which can execute any code by any hotkey with any letter, i mean:

`C, Q, Ctrl-C,  Alt-Q,  Ctrl-Alt-Q`

And this hotkey triggers whenever i press it, and in any form state (even minimized it tray).
But if i need to register hotkey for single key like SHIFT or CONTROL (ctrl) - nope, doesn't works.
Here is code:

```
 //at form load
 RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, 0, 0, (int)Keys.Shift); // doesnt works
 RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, 1, 0, (int)Keys.C); //works

 protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == 0x0312)
            {
                int id = m.WParam.ToInt32();
                if (id < 2) //testing these two hotkeys
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("trigger");
                }
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
```

I am really need to register global hotkey for single shift and single ctrl keys, but it seems i cant do it like this. How can i do this? I believe `ProcessCmdKey` works only when form is focused, so it will not work for me, however it will capture `ctrl` or `shift` or `space` keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use a modifier key *in conjunction with another key*. You cannot use a modifier key by itself. This is the same in every language that I have come across. The modifier key *modifies* the action of *one or more further keys*.

Even if it were possible, it would be unadvisable because if it were used on its own, then you would not be able to use that modifier key with any other key combinations as it would be swallowed up by the first action as soon as it was pressed.

Comment: But i saw programs which can capture this modifiers even when programs form are in tray, how its done? Can it be done similarly like these? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx

Comment: Any way to hook on keyup? I just need to set hotkey for `shift` - set english keyboard layout, `ctrl` - set russian keyboard layout. I saw program which can do it with no issues like you wrote in your answer, but there is a rumors that it is also a keylogger, so decided to do it for myself.

Answer (score 1):

`RegisterHotkey (Handle, 1, MOD_CONTROL, 0)` works perfectly